# How to define “regions” in Redis cache?

Tags: caching, redis, region

In Our project we are using the Blue - Green deployment. We are also using the cache in our project. I want to maintain different regions to support Blue / Green deployment with  Redis cache. The idea is to support Blue - Green deployment without impacting production active instance. As we deploy to a side that is not production, the caching region should use the region created or defined for that side.

Someone have an idea how to achieve it with redis.

Comment: Is having a Blue Redis and a Green Redis a nonoption?

Answer (score 0):

I have attempted this numerous different ways but IMHO [Hazelcast](https://hazelcast.com/product-features/blue-green-deployments/) does it right. It's built in as part of a circuit breaker so the clients will automatically switch over to the desired cluster resources.